# Shell + tar.gz problem with shell with archive files with --exclude=

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Thank for you help

While I want to archive all files in home without directory "pictures_old"
I tried find solution, but no results.

Can you help me?

```
 for dir in `ls`; do tar -cvzf ${dir}.tar.gz --exclude="/home/pictures_old/" ${dir}; done
```

That script archive all files in home with "pictures_old"
I woud like to exclude pictures_old

Comment: output from `ls` might never match the full pathname provided with `--exclude=`; might work to reduce the path to `--exclude=pictures_old`; also `find` with `-exec` might work

Comment: Solution: for dir in `ls --hide='pictures_old' `; do tar -cvzf ${dir}.tar.gz ${dir}; done

Answer (score 1):

Solution: `for dir in` ls --hide='pictures_old' `; do tar -cvzf ${dir}.tar.gz ${dir}; done`